# Python import error while deploying as package

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, packaging, pypi

Following is my project structure:

```
root directory  
    | - __init__.py  
    | - notdoneyet.py  
    | - helpers.py  
    | - opencv_generators.py  
    | - seam_carve.py
    | - imgtovideos.py
```

`notdoneyet.py` file contains the entry point of project and the remaining scripts are imported as modules and when required.

My `__init__.py` contains following code:

```
from .notdoneyet import user_input
from .helpers import createFolder
from .helpers import getFileExtension
from .helpers import writeImage

from .opencv_generators import generateEnergyMap
from .opencv_generators import generateColorMap

from .imagetovideos import generateVideo
from .imagetovideos import getToProcessPaths

from .seam_carve import cropByColumn
from .seam_carve import cropByRow
```

I have published the package on testPyPI. But when I try to import it after installing on local machine, I get the import error.

Initial code for `notdoneyet.py`:

```
import os, sys, cv2, argparse

#Local imports
import imgtovideos as itv
import helpers as hp #Error on this line
import opencv_generators as og
import seam_carve as sc

def main(argsip):
    #usr inpt
```

I am getting the error **"no module named helpers"**

Here is screenshot of the error:
[image]

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You created a *package*, so the `helpers` module is a sub-module of that package. Use `import .helpers`

Comment: If it happened to work before then that means you accidentally added the root directory to your sys.path module search path. Don't add package directories themselves to your path, only ever add the parent path.